# Android GLSurfaceView Saving bitmap causes exception

Tags: android, exception, bitmap, glsurfaceview

I've modified [this project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaEffects), which uses GLSurfaceView and Effects  to show a ViewPager with some of the effects applied to an image.

Additionally, I created a overlay bitmap, that is put over every image after the effect has been applied.

Up this point, the app is working fine. But now I have to save the displayed image in a file, when a button is pressed.

So i used this code:

```
 private Bitmap createBitmapFromGLSurface(int x, int y, int w, int h, GL10 gl)
            throws OutOfMemoryError {
        int bitmapBuffer[] = new int[w * h];
        int bitmapSource[] = new int[w * h];
        IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.wrap(bitmapBuffer);
        intBuffer.position(0);

        try {
            gl.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, intBuffer);
            int offset1, offset2;
            for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
                offset1 = i * w;
                offset2 = (h - i - 1) * w;
                for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                    int texturePixel = bitmapBuffer[offset1 + j];
                    int blue = (texturePixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                    int red = (texturePixel << 16) & 0x00ff0000;
                    int pixel = (texturePixel & 0xff00ff00) | red | blue;
                    bitmapSource[offset2 + j] = pixel;
                }
            }
        } catch (GLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSource, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
```

to obtain a Bitmap. When the button is pressed, I call this method:

```
protected void onClick() {
        read = true;
        mEffectView.requestRender();
}
```

Which forces the rendering, so I generate the bitmap and save it on a file using an AsyncTask.
**read** is used as a semphore in *onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)* to generate only the bitmap when I want to save it.

Saving one image works fine. When I save a second one, then I change page, this error comes up:

```
A/Bitmap: Failed to acquire strong reference to pixels
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 20475 (GLThread 9540)
```

Another issue is that the overlay, though is displayed, is not saved in the image.
This is how I apply it:

Generation

```
EffectFactory effectFactory = mEffectContext.getFactory();
overlayEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_BITMAPOVERLAY);
overlayEffect.setParameter("bitmap", overlay);
```

Effect applying

```
mEffect.apply(mTextures[0], mImageWidth, mImageHeight, mTextures[1]);
overlayEffect.apply(mTextures[1], mImageWidth, mImageHeight, mTextures[2]);
```

With mEffect is the only effect visible when saving the image.

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I solved the last problem: I find out that you have to *release* and *recreate* every Effect object you are using every time is called *mEffectView.requestRender()*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, when using

```
overlayEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_BITMAPOVERLAY);
overlayEffect.setParameter("bitmap", overlay);
```

the passed bitmap is **recycled!**

So I solved the issue passing a copy of it:

```
overlayEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_BITMAPOVERLAY);
overlayEffect.setParameter("bitmap", overlay.copy(overlay.getConfig(), false));
```

Hope this will help somebody else!